# Make column's width fixed and wrap words to next line

Tags: html, css, fixed, word-wrap

I tried to set the width of the two columns fixed :

```
.thkqgiai{
    width:20% !important;
}

.thkqso{
    width:80% !important;
}

.tdkqgiai{
    text-align:center;
}

.tdkqso{
    text-align:center;
    word-wrap:break-word !important;
}
```

`thkqgiai` and `tdkqgiai` are first column's `th` and `td` classes respectively

`thkqso` and `tdkqso` are second column's `th` and `td` classes respectively

How to I make the columns's width stay fixed, and long text will wrap to the next line?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you need to apply table-layout to be fixed:

```
table{
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

By default table-layout is auto.